# work with Tapjoy Offer Wall in Android Project

Tags: android

I need to get list of some applications from TapJoy, and than display it in my Android project. Is anybody have a link to the some resourse where  used Tapjoy Offer Wall? Unfortunately I have found only this http://knowledge.tapjoy.com/integration/android/publisher/offer-wall .

Answer (score 0):

They include a number of sample applications in their Android SDK.  I used these coupled with the knowledge center to get my applications integrated.

Comment: Could you plz share a sample if possible?